# Android dynamic background

Tags: android, android-layout, background, android-linearlayout

I am somewhat of a new android developer and have a question regarding changing the background dynamically at runtime.

What I want to do is set a background color in a LinearLayout Tag, and later change that background color in my activity class. This code below is not working. Am I missing something or is this the wrong approach for trying to change the background color in a linear layout

```
LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ChoiceLayout);
lv.setBackgroundColor(0x000080);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the provided code being run in the main UI thread?

Answer (score 3):

First thing I've noticed is that your color has ALPHA = `0x00`. Which makes it transparent. Try changing to

```
lv.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000080);
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, that should work fine. Use [`hierarchyviewer`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) to try to diagnose what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

already answered in another post , unfortunately i don't know that link but know the solution.

use

```
lv.setBackgroungColor(GetResources().getColor(int color));
```